# How to stop property binding to every element in Angular within *ngFor

Tags: html, angular

> In my html, I want to apply property binding to every element.
>
> I have a click and hover event that I want to do whenever the user
>   hovers or clicks on an individual element. But right now the hover or
>   click happens to every element within the `*ngFor`. I want it to only
>   happen on the element they are selecting/hovering over. What do I need
>   to change?
>
> I saw another stackoverflow answer and they simply applied the name
>   within the for loop (ex: `*ngFor="let article of articles"` and they
>   used `article`) in front of the boolean/variable they were setting.
>   Like my boolean is `favorite` so they did `article.favorite` within
>   the element and it apparently worked, but that method doesn't work for
>   me.
>
> Code:

```
<div class="row">
  <!--/span-->
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4"
       *ngFor="let article of articles">
    <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
    <h4>By: {{article.author}}</h4>
    <p>{{article.body}}</p>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addFavorite()"
              (mouseenter)="hoverFavorite()"
              (mouseleave)="removeHoverFavorite()">
      <span
        class="glyphicon"
        [class.glyphicon-heart]="favorite"
        [class.glyphicon-heart-empty]="!favorite"
        aria-hidden="true"></span> Favorite
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Comment
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-left" [routerLink]="['/articles', article.articleId]">Read More »
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/row-->
```

> Adding component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ArticlesService} from "./articles.service";
import {Article} from "./article.model";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-articles',
  templateUrl: './articles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./articles.component.css']
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {
  articles: Article[];
  // if favorite = false then full heart is not shown. if true then heart shown
  favorite: boolean = false;
  // clicked will be used to determine if we should keep hovering effect on
  clicked: boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router, private articleService: ArticlesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.articleService.getArticles()
        .subscribe(
            (articles: Article[]) => {
              this.articles = articles;
            }
        );
  }

  addFavorite(){
    // toggle full and empty heart
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
    if (this.clicked === true){
      // if clicked then add to database and show full heart
      this.favorite = true;
    } else { // if false then remove from database and show empty heart
      this.favorite = false;
    }
  }
  hoverFavorite(){
    // if clicked is false then show hover effect, else dont
    if (this.clicked === false){
      this.favorite = true;
    }
  }
  removeHoverFavorite(){
    // if clicked is false then show hover effect, else dont
    if (this.clicked === false){
      this.favorite = this.favorite = false;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index

```
 *ngFor="let article of articles; let i=index"
```

```
(click)="addFavorite(i)"
// or
(click)="addFavorite(article)"

(mouseenter)="hoverFavorite = i"
(mouseleave)="hoverFavorite = -1"
```

```
[class.glyphicon-heart]="favorite === i"
[class.glyphicon-heart-empty]="favorite !== i"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.. on the mouse enter and leave it says it has to be an lvalue

Comment: you need to create a field `hoverFavorite:number` in your component.

Comment: If I do that then that eliminates the function that I call for mouse enter (hoverFavorite) and mouse leave (removeHoverFavorite) though. Also, why would I go down by one on the index when calling mouse leave? Wouldn't that still keep the hovering effect on the current one (i) but then take off the hovering effect on the one before it (which wouldn't be useful since the hovering effect shouldn't be on the index before it anyways)?

Comment: It's not going "down by one", it's setting the value to an impossible index. You shouldn't need the function anymore. If you do, please post the code so that I can make more concrete suggestions.

Comment: Okay I will test it out now, but I've posted my component code in case that would help

Comment: I made your changes and also added `hoverFavorite:number;` to my component, but I didn't have any luck...

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you have now. I probably won't be able to have a look before tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting the desired result is because defined your boolean variables in the ArticlesComponent, which is the component rendering the list of articles. Thus, if the variables become true, it would be true for all the articles, instead of a single one. To fix it you should define all of the content within the ngFor loop as its own component, and in that component you would set those boolean variables. That way, each instance of an ArticleComponent would have its own variables and they wouldn't interfere with each other.

Comment: But why would the click function work? It seems as though the property binding does not work the same as click, mouseenter, etc. (as far as if you click on one it only changes that one)